# Python: Index in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

My list looks like this:

```
G = [ [0,3,4],[1,0,0],[9,5,4],[4,3,2],[3,2,3],[0,1,4],[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0] ]
```

and I want to find the index, from which *only* `[1, 0, 0]` follows consecutively. In this case `[1,0,0]` occurs 4 times consecutively, i.e if [1,0,0] occurs 4 times, then the output should be 7. The output of my expression is wrong!

The output of

```
index =[i for i, j in enumerate(G) if j == [1,0,0]]
```

is

`index = [1, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

How can i solve this problem?

**Edited**

Very important was in this question to find the index of the pattern [1,0,0], if after this no another pattern occurs. In list G is the index 6 not 7!

Comment: Why should the output be 7?

Comment: @falsetru because from this index only follows [1,0,0]

Comment: Are you saying that you want to find the first occurrence of a repeat of `[1, 0, 0]`?

Comment: @Jblasco yes sorry i've counted wrong. It's 6

Comment: @EMS yes,that's what i meant

Comment: @lara What if the last item in `G` is `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: What are the expected outputs for the following 3 lists? `[]`, `[[1,0,0]]`, `[[1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,2,3], [1,0,0], [1,0,0]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> G = [ [0,3,4],[1,0,0],[9,5,4],[4,3,2],[3,2,3],[0,1,4],
...       [1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0] ]
>>> next(i for i, (x,y) in enumerate(zip(G, G[1:])) if x == y)
6
```

(Use `.. if x == y == [1, 0, 0]` if you want to only check for `[1, 0, 0]`)

This will raise a StopIteration if there's no consecutive items.

```
>>> G = [ [1,2,3] ]
>>> next(i for i, (x,y) in enumerate(zip(G, G[1:])) if x == y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

To prevent that, pass default value:

```
>>> next((i for i, (x,y) in enumerate(zip(G, G[1:])) if x == y), -1)
-1
```

**UPDATE** according to the OP's comment:

```
import itertools

def find_target(lst, target):
    target = tuple(target)
    i, maxidx, maxcnt = 0, -1, 0
    for key, grp in itertools.groupby(lst, key=tuple):
        cnt = sum(1 for _ in grp)
        if key == target and cnt > maxcnt:
            maxidx, maxcnt = i, cnt
        i += cnt
    return maxidx
```

Usage:

```
>>> G = [[0,3,4], [1,0,0], [9,5,4], [1,0,0], [1,0,0],
...      [1,0,0], [1,0,0], [23,4,1], [1,0,0], [1,0,0],
...      [1,0,0], [1,0,0],[1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0],
...      [1,0,0]]
>>>
>>> find_target(G, [1, 0, 0])
8
>>> find_target([], [1, 0, 0])
-1
>>> find_target([[1, 0, 0]], [1, 0, 0])
0
>>> find_target([[2, 3, 4], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [1, 0, 0])
1
```

Comment: i meant the index number 6, from there occurs a repeat of [1,0,0].

Comment: @lara, I updated the answer. Maybe you're seeing the version before the update.

Comment: @ falsetru: thank you for your answer. but it doesnt work for an another list like `J=[[5,4,3], [1,0,0], [4,2,1], [5,4,4],[4,1,1], [1,0,0],[5,4,1], [5,4,1], [5,4,3], [1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0]] `

Comment: @lara in that example, there is a different entry that repeats first, `[5, 4, 1]`. You have to add in falsetru's suggestion for `x == y == [1, 0, 0]` if you *only* want to check for `[1, 0, 0]`. Lastly, in the comment above you said you wanted the first time `[1, 0, 0]` repeats, but now it looks like instead you are asking for the location at the end of the list once the list becomes `[1, 0, 0]` forever. Which is it?

Comment: @lara, What is the expected value? If I use `x == y`, it returns 6. If I use `x == y == [1, 0, 0]`, it returns 9.

Comment: @ falsetru. yes i see that. Thank you! But i' ve another question. How can I change your code so that i give frequency of [1,0,0]. I mean, if i've `G=[[0,3,4],[1,0,0], [9,5,4],[1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0] [23,4,1], [1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0],[1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0]]` from index 2 [1,0,0] occurs 4 times, but from index 7 it occurs 8 times. And i want to get the index from there the most occurrences of [1,0,0] is. How can i get this?

Comment: @ EMS yes, i had to change the code as `x == y == [1, 0, 0]` thank you!

Comment: @lara, Please update your question to make it clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Given the application, it's probably best to iterate through the list backwards using [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#reversed) and find the first non-target element.

I'm also going to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#enumerate) to iterate through the elements and indices of the reversed list at the same time. The first time we see a non-target element, we can break out of the loop. At this point, subtracting the index counter from the length of the list will give us the index of the last non-target element.

```
for ind, el in enumerate(reversed(G)):
    if el != [1, 0, 0]:
        break
else:  # This block is only run when no breaks are encountered in the for loop
    ind = ind + 1  # Adjust for when the entire list is the target
result = len(G) - ind
# 6
```

Note that Python indexing starts at 0, so 6 is actually the correct answer here, not 7. If you need the 1-indexed version, you can simply add 1.

Comment: This assumes that the repeat occurs in such a way as to occupy the tail of the list, but no such stipulation is made. This would be the same as finding the final occurrence of the element prior to the list becoming solely made of that element. That happens to be true in the example, but may not be true in the OP's general case.

Comment: @EMS In the comments, lara states: "because from this index only follows [1,0,0]". This satisfies that condition.

Comment: No. Read again. What if the final element of the list became `[1,2,3]`? The answer shouldn't change (unless the OP changes the question to reflect this).

Comment: @EMS I think the intent is unclear pending an answer to Ashwini's comment.

Comment: Maybe, but probably not. The case of needing to find the spot where a list becomes a tail that repeats the same element for the rest is much less likely given all of the context and other explanations going on here.

Comment: For example, the OP replied to my comment and agreed that what was sought is the first location where `[1, 0, 0]` repeats. That seems incompatible with this answer and with the conjecture that it is still ambiguous.

Comment: @EMS As far as I can tell there are two conflicting comments by the OP. One that wants the index after which all following elements match the target, and the comment responding to you. I interpret the latter as a misunderstanding, but without further clarification it's hard to get an accurate conclusion. Also, if it is as you say, we probably need clarification on how to handle multiple consecutive runs as well, which the OP doesn't address.

Comment: Agreed, several layers of remaining ambiguity.

Comment: I think this is exactly what OP wants, and exactly the best way to go about it...

Comment: @AdamSmith Unfortunately it is still ambiguous.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
for ii in range(len(G)-1, 0, -1):
    if G[ii-1] != [1,0,0]: 
        break
```

And the resulting ii is the desired index

If you mean the last element, and not expecifically [1,0,0] obviously you should replace [1,0,0] with G[-1], that would work for:

```
G = [ [2,3,4], [1,3,4], [1,3,4]]
```

giving 1 as an answer

Comment: i got a SyntaxError: invalid syntax because of if :(

Comment: I believe the code is right, try again, please. A related question that was asked above is: what do you want as an answer if the last element is not [1,0,0]? My code wouldn't work in that situation

Comment: @ Jblasco: ok i try it again. to your question, the last element is alwaya [1,0,0]

Comment: there is no output. I need an output with the index number